# Linear mixed model questions, with some group sizes=1 and with two time points?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data

I have a bit of an oddly-designed dataset, but it is a very unique population, so we are working with it. Essentially, I have:

- **Group 1:** one person; 5 time points over 1.5 year (time1->2 = intervention)
- **Group 2:** one person; 5 time points over 1.5 year (time1->2 = intervention)
- **Group 3:** 10 people; 6 time points over 1 year (time1->2 = intervention)
- **Group 4:** 20 people ("controls"); 3-6 time points over 7 years (no intervention)

I am looking at brain changes in certain regions over time. So, y = brain value. The goal is to look at:

1. How individuals change with an intervention (from time 1 to time 2); does the brain change *more* with intervention than what is expected with regular aging? (i.e., compare to controls)
2. If individuals recover back to baseline after the intervention (from time 2 to time 5)

To address question 1, I'm not sure what option to do, or if anyone can recommend better options.

**Option 1:**

- First, calculate slope of change for *each person* in group 3: **(time2-time1)/years**. Do this because we can't use lme function with only 2 time points?
- Next, calculate slopes of change for *each person* in group 4:

```
#Only including group 4 in mod1: 
mod1 <- lme(L_latVent_percentChangeL60~year,random=~1|person,data=data,na.action=na.omit)
coef(mod1)$year
```

- Do a 2-sample t-test to compare slopes of change with the intervention for group 3 vs. group 4. Only graph the single subjs for group 1 and group 2 for visual comparison, because we can't make group comparisons if a group size=1??

**Option 2:**

- Run a LMM with either only groups 3-4 or with all groups & include group as a predictor in the model? **However, is it okay with lme to have two groups where group size=1 & to have only 2 time points (pre & post intervention) for three of the four groups?**

```
#Including everyone in mod2; control group is reference group 
mod2 <- lme(L_latVent_percentChangeL60~year+group_OASIS,random=~1|person,data=data,na.action=na.omit)
summary(mod2)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data 
     AIC      BIC  logLik
  725.36 743.8708 -355.68

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | person
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    6.933991 5.677071

Fixed effects: L_latVent_percentChangeL60 ~ year + group_OASIS 
                 Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  -0.699281  1.850902 85 -0.377805  0.7065
year          3.461859  0.212533 85 16.288601  0.0000
group_OASIS1  7.266365  7.602203 19  0.955824  0.3512
group_OASIS2 15.731559  7.596569 19  2.070877  0.0522
group_OASIS3 -0.495773  7.594778 19 -0.065278  0.9486
 Correlation: 
             (Intr) year   g_OASISB g_OASISC
year         -0.439                         
group_OASIS1 -0.237  0.093                  
group_OASIS2 -0.234  0.085  0.056           
group_OASIS3 -0.233  0.082  0.056    0.055  

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-2.716802147 -0.419391426 -0.005033089  0.339059405  3.800718355
```

**Based on the above model, we could say that everyone changes substantially with time, but only group2 (the single subject) changes differently over time from the reference group (group4)?**

Any advice or other directions for these data would be greatly appreciated.